# What is the name of this component

Tags: sensor, components, wiring, plc

I am a graduate Aerospace Engineering student. I need to wire a pneumatic actuator's controller and a magnetic position sensor for a small part of my research. I received a connection diagram from the company making the controller, and there is a relevant video showing the procedure on YouTube. Since I, unfortunately, don't remember anything from my electrical course years ago, I don't know what a particular component in the video is called. The connection diagram says PLC, but there does not seem to be any 'PLC' in the form I am vaguely familiar with, nor is there any programming involved in the video.

Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lFFg6-doK0 (from 0:05)

What is that device in the center called? It just seems to transfer i/p-o/p

I have also attached the connection diagram I received. 
Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'PLC' shown in that video appears to be a Puls ML30 powersupply.

Here is the [datasheet](http://www.pulspower.com/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/ml30e106.pdf).  And here is the [Manual](http://www.pulspower.com/fileadmin/global/common/Product_data/Manual/PU_ml30_100.pdf).

It is driving the command input to your pneumatic controller.  I believe they are just using it to simulate the 0 - 10 V control signal.  A proper PLC could be used here to provide the 0 - 10 V (or 4 mA - 20 mA).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

I was wondering what the name was of the component placed in between the actuator on the left and the black component (controller) and the power supply on the right. I did know that the blue component was the power supply, but did not know they have connected the power supply in place of the PLC on the connection diagram. 
I planned to use a 120vac to 24vdc adapter for power. I wanted to know what that part was in the middle to which all the wires were connected, so I could buy it and follow the video as is.

Comment: That just looks like wire connectors mounted on a DIN rail.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! :)

Comment: @aadhysp I am glad I could help you.  A good search phrase for these is "DIN rail terminal block" if you wish to find some.

Answer (score 0):

The PLC in this diagram can be any device. That's the part you supply, it provides a 0-10v or 4-20ma signal to the actuator control system.

The black device in the center appears to be a programmable directional control valve. It probably works like a regular valve (you send a signal and it changes position), except that you can connect a PC to it to configure some parameters.

To use this you'll need to provide power, and the "actuate" signal. It looks like you can also tap off the feedback wire to see what position the cylinder is in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I figured that the PLC is only an analog input here, I can use any analog input here. 

A software allows change of those parameters from a PC, and it uses the feedback to get cylinder position. :)